# Strip part of URI with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have this rewrite rule to direct request to my symfony 2 application:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^/foo/.*$
RewriteRule ^/foo(/.*)$              /srv/webapps/symfony2/web/app.php [QSA,L]
```

If I access `http://test-server.com/foo/myController` I get a symfony exception telling me that it doesn't know how to route `foo/myController`.

I don't want to add `foo` to the route in symfony since the application has to work with other URL prefixes as well. How can I make sure that the `foo` part is not visible by symfony?

Comment: I cannot find an answer to my question at the mentioned link. Also the preconditions mentioned in my answer ar not mentioned at all.

Comment: It is a **canonical** article. Those are articles where the community has said all it is going to say on a class of subject, because although everyone's particular problems in that class are somewhat different, to the extent that they are interesting, they aren't different, and to the extent that they're different, they aren't interesting (to anyone save the questioner). So we write one answer that's designed to be the last word on the subject, and say no more.

Comment: I fail to see how that can possibly be interpreted as any more constructive than reading the documentation for the software in question (ie, that seems to obviate the entire point of this site)?

Answer (score 1):

As it appears that you are attempting to redirect requests made to a specific context path (`foo`) to a single file, perhaps you would find the following (modified from [this apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)) useful:
    Alias /foo /srv/webapps/symfony2/web
    
      RewriteBase /foo

```
  RewriteCond /srv/webapps/symfony2/web/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond /srv/webapps/symfony2/web/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^ app.php [PT]
</Directory>
```

Edit: 
Alternatively, you could amend your original solution to include the `PT` flag to pass the rewritten URI through to the application for processing, eg:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}           ^/foo/.*$
RewriteRule ^/foo(/.*)$              /srv/webapps/symfony2/web/app.php [QSA,PT]
```

(note that `L` is implied by `PT` [as noted in the documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_pt)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this did not change anything. I'm still getting `foo/myController` instead of `myController`.

Comment: Have you tried your original solution with the `[PT]` flag included to passthrough the processed URI to the application?

Comment: Yes. I tried all this variations. I keep getting `foo/myController`. To me this looks like that mod_rewrite makes sure the right php script is executed but never changes the original URI which is passed to the php script.

Answer (score 1):

After all I got it working. My solution looks like this:

```
Alias /foo /srv/webapps/symfony2/web
<Directory /srv/webapps/symfony2/web >
      AllowOverride None
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
      Options +FollowSymLinks

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteOptions Inherit
      RewriteBase /foo

      # prevent looping from internal redirects
      RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
      RewriteRule ^ - [L]

      ## redirect everything to app.php unless the file realy exists in /web
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^ app.php [last]
</Directory>
```

I don't know why this happens, but it seams to be important that alias and directory point directly to the symfony `web` folder. If they point to `/srv/webapps/symfony2` and the final rewrite points to `web/app.php` you get the alias root prepended to the URI.

Comment: Indeed you do need the `Alias` tag as per the documentation - apologies, I should have included this rather than assuming it existed in your config outside what you posted - but other than that, you have basically gone with my solution below?

Comment: Yes. My main mistake was that the alias/directory was pointing to the `symfony` folder and not directly to the `web` folder. I still do not understand why this is a problem. But after all it's working.

Comment: Glad you got it working at least! I've edited my post to include the Alias directive in case anyone else happens upon this post with the same issue.